# Two words hash to the same value

Tags: c, hash

Give an example of two words that would hash to the same value using stringHash1 but would hash to different values using stringHash2.

My answer is car and camera because first two letters are identical ascii values but am uncertain?

```
int stringHash1(char * str)
{
    int i;
    int r = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        r += str[i];
    return r;
}

/*the second hashing function you can use*/
int stringHash2(char * str)
{
    int i;
    int r = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        r += (i+1) * str[i];
    return r;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like highly localized homework help (edit: the last part isn't bad; the first part about being highly localized is).

Comment: What makes you think that either of those two hash functions look only at the first two characters of the string? Also, if you run the code, you'll see that "car" and "camera" hash to different values using both functions.

Comment: Show your work, then you will know if you are correct.  There are numerous places you could easily check this, like http://ideone.com

Comment: It seems here that `"ab"` and `"ba"` should qualify.

Comment: You might get extra credit if you point out your professor's obvious bug: both of these hash functions invoke undefined behavior for long strings. For the first one, it has to be very long, but for the second, you can start hitting UB with fairly short strings, especially if `int` is the minimal allowed size (16 bits).

Comment: If you want to learn this stuff, rather than just getting the grade, the your best bet is to, as @djechlin says, "just run it".  Throw a bunch of common strings at each function and see what comes out.  Better yet, walk through this program with pen and paper to see *how* it works.

Answer (score 2):

The first function adds only the character values, which means that reversing a string (or otherwise rearranging the letters) has no effect; the other also includes the index of each character in generating the hash value, making it more resilient against reordering.

So:

```
hash1(ab) = 195
hash1(ba) = 195
hash2(ab) = 293
hash2(ba) = 292
```

Comment: Any works that are anagrams will give the same hash.  (In addition to many words that aren't anagrams.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap Yeah, string reversal was just an example of string transformations that don't have an effect ;-)

Comment: @StevenBurnap That depends whether or not you consider "lol eh" to be an anagram for "hello"...